# How to setup shortcut to toggle joint xray in Maya

Tags: maya, maya-api

Is there a MEL command to toggle the "joint xray" mode in the viewport?
(so that I can set it as a shortcut)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
int $v = `modelEditor -q -jointXray modelPanel4`;
modelEditor -e -jointXray (!$v) modelPanel4;
```

Menu:
`Windows -> Settings -> HotKey Editor`

Unroll: "Edit HotKeys for:" -> Custom Scripts.

On the right panel go to the tab `Runtime Command Editor` to create the script command.
Then associate the shortcut on the left panel.

[image]